# How to SELECT some data derived from field aliases from other sub-queries

Tags: mysql

I have a query with the following structure:

```
SELECT *,
    (<sub-query>) AS `n_acts`,
    (<sub-query>) AS `n_ops`,
    `n_acts`/`n_ops` AS `score`
FROM `user`
WHERE `type` = '3'
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'n_acts' in 'field list'

I need to calculate that `score` field because I need to order the query by that value, like so:

```
SELECT *,
    (<sub-query>) AS `n_acts`,
    (<sub-query>) AS `n_ops`,
    `n_acts`/`n_ops` AS `score`
FROM `user`
WHERE `type` = '3'
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Why is MySQL not recognizing my field aliases? How can I workaround this? And most importantly, is it recommended to do this?

Comment: After getting all the rows that pass the condition of WHERE, the DBMS tries to project each row on the set of 'fields' mentioned after the keyword 'SELECT' independently from each other, there can't be any associations between elements('fields') in set. This is how I understand the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT `inner_sub`.`n_acts`, `inner_sub`.`n_ops`, `inner_sub`.`n_acts`/`inner_sub`.`n_ops` AS `score`
FROM
    (SELECT *,
        (<sub-query>) AS `n_acts`,
        (<sub-query>) AS `n_ops`
    FROM `user`
    WHERE `type` = '3') AS `inner_sub`
ORDER BY `inner_sub`.`score` DESC
LIMIT 10
```